# Can I delete this folder? Library -> Application Support -> iOSinstaller

Tags: macos, mac

I have run out of space on my 13" MacBook Pro Retina (Early 2015).
I used DiskInventoryX to see what's taking up so much space and I saw that a folder in my Library was over 50 GB.

The folder in question is: /Users/Ruzin/Library/Application Support/iOSinstaller
The contents of the folder and the files that are taking up a lot space are text files
(See included screenshots)
My question is:
Is it safe to delete this folder? Which app created it?

[image: Screenshot DiskInventoryX]

[image: Screenshot of one of the files in question]

Comment: Are you using an app named Popcorn Time?

Comment: Yes, I tried installing it on my iPad and I also use it on my Mac

Comment: Searching Google for _iOSinstaller_, Popcorn Time is the top hit and also subsequent hits. So I'm guessing it might have something to do with it.

Comment: Yup I came up with the same solution but I wanted to ask if someone had this experience

Comment: The problem is, Popcorn Time is an copyright-flouting bittorrent video piracy app... so it may be hard to get information about it. However you could use it and see if it touches that folder, either creating a new file or changing the date/time stamp on an existing file. If it does, then it's probably a safe assumption that the iOSinstaller folder is linked to Popcorn Time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried deleting the folder and the system was fine after that. The file wasn't created by the PopcornTime app for Mac but the iOSInstaller of PopcornTime. I tried to install the app on my iPad and the installer created that folder and all those large files.

So to answer the question: YES you can delete that folder and all the files inside it.